# How to convert double array to Base64 string and vice versa in Java

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I'm trying to convert a double[] array to Base64 string and vice versa. 
I want to do this for store a very long array of double arrays (double[][]) in a simple String and then return back to a double[][] array.
Is it possible?

This is my current code for testing the conversion between byte array and Base64 String. Of course, doesn't work:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] testArray = {170.56, 43.78, 674.0};

    String encodedTest = encodeLocation(testArray);
    System.out.println(encodedTest+"\n");

    double[] decodedTest = decodeLocation(encodedTest);
    for(Double d: decodedTest)
        System.out.println(d);
}

private static String encodeLocation(double[] doubleArray){
    byte[] bytes = doubleToByteArray(doubleArray);
    String base64Encoded = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return base64Encoded;
}

private static double[] decodeLocation(String base64Encoded){
    byte[] bytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(base64Encoded.getBytes());
    double[] doubleArray = byteToDoubleArray(bytes);
    return doubleArray;
}

private static byte[] doubleToByteArray(double[] doubleArray){

    int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[doubleArray.length * times];
    for(int i=0;i<doubleArray.length;i++){
        ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, i*times, times).putDouble(doubleArray[i]);
    }   
    return bytes;
}

private static double[] byteToDoubleArray(byte[] bytes){
    int times = Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    double[] doubles = new double[bytes.length / times];
    for(int i=0;i<doubles.length;i++){
        doubles[i] = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, i*times, times).getDouble();
    }
    return doubles;
}

}
```

Output:

```
@eQ??R@E??
=p?@?


3.541909365425625E83
3.052647263964711E103
1.1233976318184827E79
2261634.5098039196
```

Comment: If you just want to save memory, check to see if your values could be stored accurately in floats. You would cut your memory usage in half. double = 8 bytes, float = 4 bytes

Comment: if you are trying to parse your array to Base64, I think there are better approaches to serialize data, like implement Serializable

Comment: Your `encodeLocation` doesn't have anything to do with Base64.

Comment: Your `doubleToByteArray` and `byteToDoubleArray` seem very convoluted/wrong. Why don't you just `allocate` a `ByteBuffer` big enough and `putDouble` for each value in the array, then return the buffer's backing array?

Comment: String.getBytes() will use your platform's default charset... better to be explicit there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `ByteBuffer.wrap()` inside a loop, your `encodeLocation()` doesn't do any Base64 logic, the `decodeLocation()` is encoding, not decoding, and you don't need to do string conversion yourself.

In short, your code has lots of issues. Here is the code with all the problems fixed:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.DoubleBuffer;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] testArray = {170.56, 43.78, 674.0};

        String encodedTest = encodeLocation(testArray);
        System.out.println(encodedTest+"\n");

        double[] decodedTest = decodeLocation(encodedTest);
        for (double d : decodedTest)
            System.out.println(d);
    }
    private static String encodeLocation(double[] doubleArray) {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(doubleToByteArray(doubleArray));
    }
    private static double[] decodeLocation(String base64Encoded) {
        return byteToDoubleArray(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Encoded));
    }
    private static byte[] doubleToByteArray(double[] doubleArray) {
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(Double.SIZE / Byte.SIZE * doubleArray.length);
        buf.asDoubleBuffer().put(doubleArray);
        return buf.array();
    }
    private static double[] byteToDoubleArray(byte[] bytes) {
        DoubleBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).asDoubleBuffer();
        double[] doubleArray = new double[buf.limit()];
        buf.get(doubleArray);
        return doubleArray;
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
QGVR64UeuFJARePXCj1wpECFEAAAAAAA

170.56
43.78
674.0
```